# reading a matrix in hadoop map reduce

Tags: java, matrix, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

hi i have a matrix and want to pass it on to **mapper class** in hadoop multinode cluster set up, but *matrix is not in file*. Is there any way of passing matrix without writing it to a file?

Comment: we are going to need a lot more detail to help you out here. Where is the matrix? How is it structured? What have you tried? Do you have code? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In [JobConf](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html), you specify the input using the method [setInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setInputFormat%28java.lang.Class%29). [InputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) has many classes implementing its interface.

Apart from [FileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) and its subclasses, you have other classes which implement [InputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) like [DBInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/db/DBInputFormat.html), [Parser.Node](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/join/Parser.Node.html) and more.. See if you can use any those.

If none suits your needs, try to build your own custom InputFormat class to achieve the same.